# Sqlalchemy Session - list of ORM instances to commit

Tags: events, session, orm, permissions, sqlalchemy

I use sqlalchemy hooks to check user permissions for some operations (like querying or inserting data to DB).

For preventing of save inaccessible records, I set hook before_commit, which gets a session object. I want to get all instances, which should performed by this commit to check can this instances be saved or no (and expunge wrong records).

For adding new records it works by after_attach and before_commit (expunge inside of after_attach isn't works for some reason). But in case of query->update->commit of instances after_attach didn't called, so all permission checks should be moved into before_commit.

Answer (score 3):

by the time `before_commit` is emitted, everything is "saved" from the session's perspective; this is because changes are emitted to the database specifically within the `flush()`, not the `commit()`.  The commit just calls upon the `flush()` but that's not the only time `flush()` happens.

If you want to prevent something from happening in the flush, use the `before_flush` event for that: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html?highlight=before_flush#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.before_flush